# why can't I put the 0xffff in to a short in java

Tags: java, hex, short

Such as the title，I remember short is a **16 bit** value，and every **hexadecimal** character is a 4 bit value, so I think **`0xffff`** can be put in a **`short`**,
But it can't, why?

Answer (score 3):

This assignment fails because 0xffff is an `int` literal:

```
short s = 0xffff;
```

You must cast it to `short` to make it work:

```
short s = (short) 0xffff;
```

Remember that `short` is a signed type, so you may not get the value you expect. The hexadecimal `0xffff` represents the number `-1`.

```
System.out.println((short) 0xffff); // Prints -1.
```

Comment: But casting it to short will yield a wrong value(overflow).

Comment: It will. Although whether it's _wrong_ or not depends on what he expects ;)

Answer (score 3):

in Java `short` is a *signed* datatype. Therefore a value with all bits set is a `-1`. I doubt that this is what you want he value to be...

Answer (score 0):

because 0xffff is format of int and you need to cast it to short.

```
short s= (short)0xffff;
```

Comment: sometime it is good to read error messages from IDE or compiler it saves a lot of time...

Comment: Not really .. you could have `short s = 0xfff` and all would be fine !

Comment: upto 0x7fff it wouldn't complain in the IDE ! ... because that's the maximum acceptable value ...

Comment: so? what be a value of short s= (short)0xffff; ?

Comment: In Binary (1111111111111111) is the 2's complement of Decimal (-1) ... so -1 ... Explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Answer (score 0):

I think i have find the answer, integer is a signed dataType,and there are a bit be use to put an Sign bit，so although the short have 8 bit, actually we just can use 7 bit to store our date , thanks all answer, thank you !